# How can I get past 33! using Javascript in Browser?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, factorial

I know there must be a trick I am missing, how do I calculate past 33! using in browser JS? I have the [following already](https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/249180/), this gets me to 33 but blows up when I go to 34. I Got 34 to work in Node like this...

```
 node --max-old-space-size=4096 --experimental-modules test.mjs
```

But it blows up again at 35.

Can I calculate past 33! using JS in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such large numbers aren't supported natively, so one option is to use a library such as [BigInteger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer):

```js
const factorial = n => bigInt(n).multiply(
  n === 1
  ? 1
  : factorial(n - 1)
);
console.log(factorial(45));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/big-integer/1.6.34/BigInteger.min.js"></script>
```

(when using it, make sure to pass large numbers as *strings* or other `bigInt`s to avoid precision loss)

Comment: I appreciate the lib solution but I feel like there must be an algorithmic solution. That is why it is a kata ;-)

Comment: Also if you look at the code it is using strings to multiply.

Comment: NM I got it I had a bug in my code I will post shortly

Comment: Working manually without the lib (https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/252155/)